# What is a good code coverage tool for Ruby?

Tags: coverage

I would really like to see which bits of code/functionality I've missed testing in my application, which is a mix of Ruby and JQuery and Java applets. Years ago I used a nice code coverage tool for C code which made it so easy to see what needed to be exercised.

Answer (score 5):

Try these articles about RCov and simple_cov

http://highgroove.com/articles/2011/03/01/code-coverage-and-ruby-1-9.html

http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/tools-plugins/generating-code-coverage-metrics-for-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-simplecov/

and rails_code_qa uses both of the above so also worth a look

https://github.com/nathanhumbert/rails_code_qa

Comment: Mark it as a good answer then ?

Comment: I believe I did; I said that it was helpful, but I am not yet allowed to vote.